# Extend regexp to trigger on more chars

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regexp in JavaScript:

```
new RegExp('(?:^|\\b|\\s)' + this.options.token + '([\\w.]*)$');
```

The problem is that this only triggers on a-e, A-E, on space etc, not ".", "[", "/" etc as well.
How can I extend this regexp to include these characters as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add them:

```
new RegExp('(?:^|\\b|\\s|\\.|\\[|\\/)' + this.options.token + '([\\w.]*)$');
```

And so on...

This breaks down as:

```
<start of line> or <word boundary> or <whitespace> or . or [ or /
```

Which should hopefully do what you want.